# Samba unable to locate a file

Tags: samba

I have a strange issue with samba.

Samba is unable to find some existing files on a test environnement. On another test environement (same project, same server, same use,same rights) with the exact same configuration this is working fine.

I'm trying to open some files with a file: link, using IE 8.

```
[2013/09/09 14:46:01.506013,  3] smbd/vfs.c:905(check_reduced_name)
```

check_reduced_name [physical/path/to/file/from/Share/root.rtf] [/physical/path/to/share]

```
[2013/09/09 14:46:01.506075,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1039(check_reduced_name)
```

check_reduced_name: physical/path/to/file/from/Share/root.rtf reduced to /file/physical/path.rtf

```
[2013/09/09 14:46:01.506140,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5251(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
```

call_trans2qfilepathinfo: SMB_VFS_STAT of physical/path/to/file/from/Share/root.rtf:Zone.Identifier failed (No such file or directory)

```
[2013/09/09 14:46:01.506196,  3] smbd/error.c:81(error_packet_set)
```

error packet at smbd/trans2.c(5253) cmd=50 (SMBtrans2) NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

My customer set this environnement wrongly, the "physical/path/to/file/from/Share" got "777" as a owner. I fixed it, and restarted samba, but it still don't work.

smbstatus say no locked files. My others samba shares are working fine, with the same conf, same users, ect ...

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a problem with Samba. The customer had an error in one of his GPO.